# Alfresco JARS: org.alfresco.web.scripts.Cache

Tags: java, alfresco

I'm trying to run some sample but I cannot find this class:

org.alfresco.web.scripts.*

Could you help me to find JARs for Java-backed web scripts? I downloaded the Alfresco SDK but I can't find it on alfresco-web-client-3.4.b.jar

It's really freaking me out! Thanks for your time!

Andrea

Comment: Which class are you specifically looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I guess you need the new package since 3.3 : `org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.*`

Take a look at this [Wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Java-backed_Web_Scripts_Samples) and you will see that the package you're referring to is no longer being used.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found it and fixed. Any idea why when I restart tomcat the exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/extensions/webscripts/DeclarativeWebScript is raised?

Comment: Hi, I normally use AbstractWebScript, but you could take a look at the the following jar: alfresco-enterprise-sdk-3.4.0\lib\server\dependencies\spring-surf\spring-webscripts-1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar. You could check which spring-webscripts-*. jar is deployed on your tomcat.

Comment: Found, the jar imported on class have to be copyed to tomcat/shared/lib folder

Answer (score 0):

The `org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts` package is in the **Remote API** jar, eg `alfresco-remote-api-4.0.a.jar` .

That's not the package you asked about (it's org.alfresco.*repo*.web.scripts rather than org.alfresco.web.scripts) but I think it's the one you want, as I can't spot the latter in the codebase from a quick check...